# Property 'connectedCallback' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: typescript

I have a project that I've returned to after a year. Something similar to the code below used to work but no longer works:

```js
interface HTMLElement {
    attributeChangedCallback(attributeName: string, oldValue: string, newValue: string): void;
    connectedCallback(): void;
    disconnectedCallback(): void;
    observedAttributes: string[];
}

export default class TestElement extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback(): void {
        super.connectedCallback();
    }
}
```

I now get a `Property 'connectedCallback' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'` error. This isn't like many of the multitudes of questions on here where people needed to be more specific as to which type to use. I'm literally extending `HTMLElement` here. The default declarations for `HTMLElement` doesn't contain any of the custom element stuff, so I have for a while now been using an interface to fill in for what I've been using. Is there something additional I must be doing to get this working now?

Comment: Is `Property 'connectedCallback' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'` tslint error, or build error, or ?

Comment: An interface cannot be instantiated, it can be implemented like `class TestElement implements HTMLElement`.

Comment: @Yeheshuah It's a build error.

Comment: @ArtemBozhko Yeah, I'm aware of that, but the problem is that HTMLElement has to be extended in the JavaScript that is transpiled to create the custom element. I need a way for TypeScript to understand that HTMLElement does indeed have connectedCallback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the existing interface in ***.d.ts** file

```
interface HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback(): void;
}
```

OR

You can extend the existing interface directly in the ***.ts** file

```
declare global {
    interface HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback(): void;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works! Added the d.ts file to my includes in tsconfig and it was happy then. Thanks!

Comment: IINM, connectedCallback should really be optional, ie 'connectedCallback?(): void;'.